# How do I relate phase shift to heat capacity or thermal conductivity for frequency domain thermoreflectance?

Tags: thermodynamics, laser, phase-transition, thermal-conductivity

I'm trying to measure either thermal conductivity or heat capacity of Silicon devices using frequency domain thermoreflectance (FDTR). I can get phase shift between the incoming signal from pump laser and reflected probe laser signal using lock-in amplifier, but I don't know how to calculate thermal conductivity or heat capacity from that phase shift.